# Objective-C WatchOS send a text message

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos-2

I have an iphone app that sends a text message. And now I have started to make an `Apple Watch` version of this app.

When I try to import `<MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` it says its not found. I have been doing some reading and found out that `MessageUI` is not an available framework for `watchOS`, but I found that you can use non-supported frameworks using `WatchConnectivity`. My issue is all the examples I found are in swift and I am using `Objective-C`, my question is how do I use `WatchConnectivity` to use `MessageUI` and/or is there another way to send a text message via `watchOS`?

Comment: let me know too if you find an answer. same issue here.

Comment: I will be starting a bounty for this when eligible

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot send a text message via `watchOS` directly , we don't have  `MessageUI` framework  support in it. However, using `WatchConnectivity` send the text of message from `Watch` to `iPhone` and then on  phone do the rest. But there is a limitation in the case when app is in `background` and message is received from watch.

**On Watch**

```
if([WCSession isSupported]) {
    WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    session.delegate = self;
    [session activateSession];
    [session sendMessage:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"message text here" forKey:@"text"]
            replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {
                             //handle reply from iPhone app here
                         }
            errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                             //catch any errors here
                         }];
}
```

**On iPhone**

```
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nonnull))replyHandler {
    //--Message UI code here
}
```

[Available System Technologies for WatchOS2](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/LeverageSystemTechnologies.html)

Comment: This will not work. didReceiveMessage goes in appDelegate. How would you open text message window if it is non-interactive and app is in background?

Comment: Yes  in that case its a problem but for foreground state it will work. Again we are limited in some cases